# Running e2e tests w/ Protractor fails when a call to my API is made

Tags: angular, protractor, e2e-testing, angular-e2e

I'm trying to run e2e tests on my Angular 4 app which hits my ExpressJS backend API. Running `ng serve` my app is served up by default on port 4200. And then separately running `nodemon server.js` starts my ExpressJS server on port 3000. I can use. With `app.use(cors({ origin: 'http://localhost:4200', credentials: true }));` I can hit my API from my Angular app just fine. However, when I try to run `ng e2e` the app is no longer running on port 4200 but instead 49155. So not only will my API block cross origin requests, but the tests hit the endpoing `http://localhost:49155/api/endpoint` instead of being proxy'd over to `http://localhost/3000/api/endpoint`.

I know I can run an `ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json` which looks like

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "http://localhost:3000",
        "secure": false
    }
}
```

But is there any way I can do this with my `ng e2e` tests? And is there a way I can allow multiple cors with `cors()`?